# Getting weather for a country, place bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use this website https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/ to scrape data of the weather using BeautifulSoup4 by opening a URL as:

```
quote_page=r"https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/%s/%s/ext" %(country, place)
```

I'm still new to web scraping methods and `BS4`, I can find the information I need in the source of the page (for example, we take country as India and city as Mumbai in this search) linked as: https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/india/mumbai/ext

If you see the page's source, it is not difficult to use `CTRL+F` and find the attributes of the information like "Humidity", "Dew Point" and current state of the weather (if it's clear, rainy, etc.), the only thing that's preventing me from getting those data is my knowledge of `BS4`.

Can you inspect the page source and write the `BS4` methods to get information like 
"Feels Like:", "Visibility", "Dew Point", "Humidity", "Wind" and "Forecast"?

Note: I've done a data scraping exercise before where I had to get the value in an HTML tag like `<tag class="someclass">value</tag>` 
using 
`

```
a=BeautifulSoup.find(tag, attrs={'class':'someclass'})
a=a.text.strip()`
```

Comment: If you need weather data, why not just to use API like https://openweathermap.org/api?

Comment: That's a great API, thanks for the comment. Yes, I could definitely use simpler APIs but the main motive of this question was to understand how else I could use beautifulsoup in regard with real life problems rather than just reading the docs and seeing examples. The link you gave is useful, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could familiarize yourself with css selectors

```
 import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
country = 'india'
place = 'mumbai'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0',
          'Host' : 'www.timeanddate.com'}
quote_page= 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/{0}/{1}'.format(country, place) 
res = requests.get(quote_page)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
firstItem = soup.select_one('#qlook p:nth-of-type(2)')
strings = [string for string in firstItem.stripped_strings]
feelsLike = strings[0]
print(feelsLike)
quickFacts = [item.text for item in soup.select('#qfacts p')]

for fact in quickFacts:
    print(fact)
```

---

The first selector `#qlook p:nth-of-type(2)`  uses an [id selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) to specify the parent then an [:nth-of-type CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to select the second paragraph type element (p tag) within.

That selector matches:

[image]

I use `stripped_strings` to separate out the individual lines and access required info by index.

---

The second selector `#qfacts p`  uses an [id selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) for the parent element and then a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) with `p` [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) to specify child p tag elements. That combination matches the following:

[image]

`quickFacts` represent a list of those matches. You can access items by index.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I think you didn't see the "res" variable, because it says res is not defined (in the res.content). Could you quickly fix that? I'm working like an interpreter right now so if I encounter any more issues I'll just add in the upcoming comments, if that's okay!

Comment: oops... Updated. The hazards of jupyter remembering things

Comment: I'm using BeautifulSoup 4.7.1

Comment: Hahaha no issues, I'm using spyder for python 3.5 btw.

Worked like a charm, thanks. I still need to wrap my head around the methods of getting values from tags in 'lxml' type of web page while opening it using BS4; the ones which you just used (CSS selectors?). These were new to me and I'd like to learn more, do you have any sources which I can refer or tutorials I can watch?

Comment: Follow the links in my answer and also play with [this](https://flukeout.github.io/). Related clips: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=css+diner